# Assign material to multiple objects in edit mode

Tags: materials

I selected parts of multiple objects (in edit mode) and assigned a material to them, but it only assigned it to the active object.

How to assign a material to all the parts of objects?

Answer (score 4):

### How to assign materials to all or part of a single object

This is a simple process. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Assign Material]

Go into edit mode. Select the geometry that you want to be a different material (you can select faces individually, or press L when hovering your mouse over a mesh). Then simply click on Assign as shown in the screenshot above.

### How to assign materials to multiple objects while in Multi-Object editing mode

Select one of your objects and create two material slots, and then also create two materials. Tweak your material settings for the second material to whatever you wish. I just used a bright blue color here.

[image: Step 1]

Select all of the objects that you want to edit, shift click the first one so it becomes active.

[image: Step 2]

Press **CTRL + L** to open the links pop-up, and then select **Materials**.

[image: Step 3]

Make sure the number that appears on the materials panel matches the number of objects you have.

[image: Part 4]

Select all of your objects and TAB into edit mode. Select what you want to change, be it faces or meshes, and then simply assign the new material.

[image: Part 5]

Done!

[image: Part 6]

Comment: Yes, this is simple, but I am trying to assign a material to **multiple objects**, not multiple meshes.

Comment: Please check my post above, I updated it to reflect how to do this in Multi-Object editing mode.

Comment: I exactly followed your steps, but it still works just for the active object

Comment: Can you clarify where in the process it failed? Can you try creating a new scene and replicating the process with some simpler geometry?

Comment: Ahh, figured it out... I had to select the material in **each** object, that's why it didn't work. But it's quite annoying selecting it for every single object, is there a simpler way of doing it?

Comment: Sorry not following you, what do you mean by "I had to select the material in each object"? You should be able to select whatever you want, select the material (once), and then press Apply. If you're still having trouble I can record my screen.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, I have recorded my screen for you to better understand. Available here: https://youtu.be/HxDA_d68aQs

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the behavior in your screen cap. Here's a video of my screen: https://streamable.com/yf3k4e Maybe this will help?

Comment: In my case, I have to select the mat individually, there must be some error in the software, or maybe I messed up some settings, but thanks anyways.